# What is actually SE biology about?

Tags: discussion

When I first crossed SE biology, I was filled with excitement that I finally found a website, where I could  share my questions with real researchers. I saw the opportunity to improve my rhetorical abilities and finally learn how to form scientific questions.

After three months, I actually did get better with my abilities, but nevertheless that wasn't exactly what did I expect.

Instead, I found lots of people who really don't even try to give me an opportunity to improve my question or give me a hint. They rather downvote  my post without a single comment.

So, I am asking, what is exactly the true purpose of SE biology?

*P.S. This is just a point of view from a molecular biology student (first year in the world of science).*

Comment: To give you basic feedback on your posts so far: there is very little research effort to your posts. We like to answer questions here where someone shows that they have thought about their question a bit, otherwise we get overwhelmed with simple questions. A lot of your questions are also species ID questions: these can be well-received, but you need to give sufficient detail: good pictures, location, etc. It also helps if there is some background motivation. You could go in your backyard and photograph every species but those are not interesting questions to answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your responce. I definetly havent done something like what did you mention (going to backyard with camera). About species identification i ll try to be openminded and find something interesting (we i thing my identification post is not so bad). I thing the best way how to start impoving my abilities is start with the simlier thing to ask, and master it. But the downvoting did put my courage to ask about something what really imprest me (neuroscience and molecular biology).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite simple. We are a question and answers site on Biology. We are one of the sites within the larger [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). We dwarf against sites like [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in terms of mass. But also within the scientific subclass, we are small compared to Physics and Chemistry.

We mainly thrive because of questions on Genetics, and related disciplines within the Molecular Biology. Questions on Evolution are relatively many too, although stuff like Neuroscience does get some attention too.

The downvoting - the voting system is a core component of the SE network ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)). In a nut shell, and imo, it's all about getting the good posts a good score, and the lesser quality ones low scores. It's mainly a system devoted to rank answers from better to worse. However, question voting is great too, as it brings (bad) questions in the spot light. This is important for moderators and other high-rep users who do not have the time to sift through all the questions, but rather look at the dash board for the odd  posts out.

It seems you are one of many that takes downvotes personally. Don't. It's part of the system. To be blunt, like it, or leave it.

Now, in fact, in my opinion downvoting is used way too sparsely. It's a strong motivator to improve posts and further, posts with downvotes tend to be removed by the bot, which comes in handy especially for sites still in beta that have to deal with fields of dead and decaying questions that wreck havoc on site stats (Death Valley). As mods can't close-vote without using the mod-hammer, mods tend to downvote a lot. It's not to be mean, it's part of the system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to not take IT personaly but it sometimes hardware to not to . Anyway the main problem Is that many guys just get you a downvote without responce So in case of people like me which english Is not my motherboard language is quite hard. Btw i wont definitly just give Up on this sítě, still this Is the best way how to improved .

Comment: @L.Diago FYI, one of the most [downvoted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/353518) in SE is from its co-founder. See the second answer.